# In celery, how do i run a period task based on task completion

Tags: python, django, task, celery

So in my django project i currently have a celery beat schedule for a task that runs periodically on a timer.

Now, my task is requesting from a URL about 250 times that responds with a json, and since requesting from that URL is limited, the whole task can take anywhere from 5 minutes to 10 minutes depending on how successful the requests are.

Instead of running this task periodically through a timer, how can run it based on the last task completion.

for example: if this last task was completed 10 seconds ago, run this task again

tasks.py

```
@app.task()
def run_db():
allPlayers = Player.objects.all()
for player in allPlayers:
    a = get_json(player.name)
    if a is None:
        pass
    else:
        player.mmr = a['rnk_amm_team_rating']
        player.save()
        print player.mmr 
        time.sleep(2)
```

settings.py

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
 'add-every-10-seconds': {
    'task': 'ladder.tasks.run_db',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is to call the task again in the end of the current execution of the task.

Something like:

```
def rundb():
    allPlayers = Player.objects.all()
    for player in allPlayers:
        a = get_json(player.name)
        if a is None:
            pass
        else:
            player.mmr = a['rnk_amm_team_rating']
            player.save()
            print player.mmr
            time.sleep(2)

    rundb.apply_async(countdown=10)  # Call the same task again in 10 seconds
```

Keep in mind that this should be monitored. If the worker crashes and your not using ack_late, or for some other reason, the worker may not be able to reschedule the task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the task 250 times you can make a single task which iterates 250 times, since you want your next task to start after the completion of your previous task you don't need to call all the tasks async. This is what I suggest:

```
@app.task()
def run_db():
    allPlayers = Player.objects.all()
    for run in totalRuns:  #(totalRuns = 250 in your case.)
        for player in allPlayers:
            a = get_json(player.name)
            if a is None:
                pass
            else:
                player.mmr = a['rnk_amm_team_rating']
                player.save()
                print player.mmr 
                time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(10)
```